# Where 'salt' is setup in Magento 2 for passwords?

Tags: magento2

Anyone know where can i get access the file, where I can change the **salt** for generating the password for Customers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The salt is generated individually for each customer. There is no global salt.

It's generated when the password is hashed, in `\Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor::getHash()`. https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php